Does the phalasruti of the yagnavalkya version of Saraswati kavacham grant buddhi Shakti and Kalpana Shakti to the reciter?
The Saraswati kavacham which has Beeja mantras in it are not recommended to chant. So I decided to chant the kavacham given by yagnavalkya Rishi. The link is as follows-
https://stotranidhi.com/hi/sri-saraswati-stotram-yajnavalkya-kritam-in-sanskrit/
My query is : like the original kavacham does the pahalasruti of the yagnavalkya Saraswati kavacham give the upasaka any buddhi Shakti (mental sharpness and intelligence ) and Kalpana shakti(creative capabilities).
These two things were not specifically mentioned in the phalasruti so I was having a doubt whether I would obtain these by chanting the stotra. Please clarify my doubts

Yes(in part), since the last part of the phalashruti does mention that:

Yaagnyavalka kritam Vaaneestotrameytatu yah pathet/
Sa Kaveendro Mahaavaagmi Brihaspatisamo bhavet,
Mahaa murkhascha durmedhaa varshamekam yadaa pathet/
Sa panditascha medhaavi Sukavischa bhaved dhruvam/

(Transliteration isn't the best, but you can look at 35 & 36th slokas somewhere else.)
The translation is as follows:

Those who read or recite the above Saraswati Stuti with sincerity would reap the powers of Jnaana, Smriti and Buddhi. Even if a ‘murkha’ (stupid) or a ‘durbuddhi’ (evil-minded) reads or recites the Stotra for a year, the person concerned would certainly acquire qualities of an intelligent and erudite scholar and Poet of standing.

So it is undoubtable that Buddhi is improved by this strotra.
Another fact is that Devi Sarasvati blessed Yagnavalkya that:

he would be a highly renowned Poet whose fame and name would be immortalised.

Poetry does require creativity, so one could argue that Kalpana Shakti can be obtained by chanting this strotra, but I could not find a dogmatic statement of it.
